# how to create elements dynamically in HTML using JSON file

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, html, twitter-bootstrap

I want to create HTML elements dynamically using JSON file.

```
{"myObject": {
"JAVA": {
    "id": "JAVAsubj",
    "path": "json/data.json"
},
"C#": { 
    "id": "JAVAsubj",
    "path": "json/data1.json"
},
"C++": {
   "id": "JAVAsubj",
    "path": "json/data2.json"
}
}
}
```

This is my JSON file. i want to create HTML buttons dynamically. Buttons should be create like JAVA,C#,C++. if i add something next to C++ then that button should get created dynamically

Comment: It would be helpful if you would provide your expected HTML output for this JSON (in actual HTML, not just a description).

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy
i Have not tried, i am not getting how to do it.

Comment: In plain javascript, start with `document.createElement()` and `.appendChild()`.  Both are fully documented on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/).  You really ought to show that you tried something and did some research.

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist
<input type="button" name="java" value="json/data.json">

i want to create button like this format
where value of button is path in JSON file

Comment: @Phoenix - put your question clarifications (like the desired HTML output) into the actual question (use the edit link) so people reading the question can understand better.

Comment: @Phoenix Then first try your self, take a little stress and scratch your mind. We can't do your homework.

Comment: @jfriend00
ok i will try on my own now and get back to you all ASAP

Comment: @jogesh_pi - why did you edit an answer right into the question?  That's not how SO is supposed to work!  If you feel like answering, then create an answer - though we just finished convincing the OP to try this on their own before asking for more help.

Comment: @jfriend00 OP putted it into the comment section that was not readable, i updated his question with his given input in comments. But something he deleted it. That's it. And yes now he deleted that comment.

Comment: I have to say I appreciate the comments. It is obvious what Phoenix is trying to do (get answers to home work or make someone do the work for him), yet rather than troll him/her, the commenters are being very gracious by trying to "guide" the person. Welcome humans! The Internet is now ready for you!

Comment: @jogesh_pi - what you posted belongs in an answer, not in the question (it kind of confuses the whole question).  I rolled back your edit.  If you want to share it, then write it into an answer and post that.  If it's info from the OP, then it needs to be put into the context of the question when it's added to the question which it was not.

Comment: @jfriend00 I appreciate with the edit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try something like this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/bYv6h/)

however, i changed the myObject to an array of json objects as follows:

```
var jsonObj = {"myObject":
 [
    {
     title: 'JAVA',
     id: "JAVAsubj",
     path: "json/data.json"
    },
    { 
    title: "C#",
    id: "JAVAsubj",
    path: "json/data1.json"
    },
    {
    title: "C++",
    id: "JAVAsubj",
    path: "json/data2.json"
    }
  ]
}


var count = Object.keys(jsonObj.myObject).length;
var container= document.getElementById('buttons'); // reference to containing elm
for(var i=0;i<count;i++){
var obj= jsonObj.myObject[i];
var button = "<input type='button' value="+obj.title+"></input>"
container.innerHTML+=button;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

First thing you need to do that get your JSON into js object :

```
var myJSON= {"myObject": {
"JAVA": {
    "id": "JAVAsubj",
    "path": "json/data.json"
},
"C#": { 
    "id": "JAVAsubj",
    "path": "json/data1.json"
},
"C++": {
   "id": "JAVAsubj",
    "path": "json/data2.json"
}
}
}
```

now get the value of your object into dictionary like below :

```
var dctLanguages = myJSON["myObject"];
```

now to render buttons dynamically, just do this :

var strHTML = '';

```
for (var key in dctLanguages)
{
   var language = dctLanguages[key];
   strHTML += '<input type="button" id="'+language.id+'" value="'+key+'"/>';
}
```

and append this HTML into your container div as follows :

```
$(strHTML).appendTo("#container");
```

Hope this will work for you..

Answer (score 0):

This shoule help you

```js
const info = [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "img": "a.jpg",
        "name": "Avinash Mehta",
        "desc": "I am Web Developer"
       
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "img": "c.jpg",
        "name": "Avinash",
        "desc": "I am Web"
       
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "img": "b.jpg",
        "name": "Mehta",
        "desc": "I am Developer"
       
    },
    
]
const main = document.querySelector(".main");

window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
    let displayInfo = info.map(function(profile){

        return` <div class="profile">
        <img src="${profile.img}" alt="">
        <h2>${profile.name}</h2>
        <p>${profile.desc}</p>
    </div>`
    });
    displayInfo = displayInfo.join("");
    main.innerHTML = displayInfo
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const info = [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "img": "a.jpg",
        "name": "Avinash Mehta",
        "desc": "I am Web Developer"
       
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "img": "c.jpg",
        "name": "Avinash",
        "desc": "I am Web"
       
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "img": "b.jpg",
        "name": "Mehta",
        "desc": "I am Developer"
       
    },
    
]
const main = document.querySelector(".main");

window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
    let displayInfo = info.map(function(profile){

        return` <div class="profile">
        <img src="${profile.img}" alt="">
        <h2>${profile.name}</h2>
        <p>${profile.desc}</p>
    </div>`
    });
    displayInfo = displayInfo.join("");
    main.innerHTML = displayInfo
})
```